# Swift, Firebase: Implement Geolocation/ User posts in set circle

Tags: swift, firebase, geolocation

im using Firebase, xCode 10.1 and Swift 4.2 for programming native IOS Apps. 
I would like to implement the following functions in my App:

1. Locate the user location when starting the App
2. Display all posts in the set circle
3. Every user can adjust his or her circle in profile settings

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds totally possible, with the use of GeoFire: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc. If you have a problem implementing, report back with the [minimal steps reproducing the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)